# Creating mysql table of consecutive numbers

Tags: mysql

Hi i have created a table called allposs with all the possible lotto results from 6/49 lotto which seemed easy enough.

```
create table allposs (
`id` mediumint (8) unsigned NOT NULL,
`n1` tinyint (3) unsigned NOT NULL,
`n2` tinyint (3) unsigned NOT NULL,
`n3` tinyint (3) unsigned NOT NULL,
`n4` tinyint (3) unsigned NOT NULL,
`n5` tinyint (3) unsigned NOT NULL,
`n6` tinyint (3) unsigned NOT NULL,
key `id` (`id`)
) engine=myisam;
```

Created a procedure to generate the results and put them in the table
which has worked fine.

Now i need to make other tables using the results from this table eg.

Create a table "filter1" that holds all results that are consecutive 1,2,3,4,5,6/44,45,46,47,48,49
and another "filter2" that has 5 consecutive 1,2,3,4,5,25,/ 1,10,11,12,13,14 then 4consec 1,2,3,4,13,23,/ 1,16,17,18,19.49 and so on.

Once I have created all these I need view/select  "allposs" table -minus "filter1", "filter2" ect.

I am very new to mysql php and dont have money to pay a professional so I am trying to do it myself but I think its going to take forever as I have serched for past 2 weeks and cannot find the solution. 
I have very basic programming skills but are determined to learn. 
Please any help would be much apreciated.
I am using mysql 5.1.54 on ubuntu 11.4

Comment: Don't create tables. Use [views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/view-syntax.html) to display the data the way you want. You'll also need to do a [minus](http://www.bitbybit.dk/carsten/blog/?p=71), which is a set operation.

Comment: thanks Ben for your comment but i need the tables to do other stuff linked to a website i am trying to setup and thought it would be easier and quicker as i have 23 different filters/tables i need to create and use.

Comment: Ok i think i need the left join here somehow ive looked at VIEWS but don't think its what i need.

Comment: @MarkRobinson: Are your numbers stored in the table as `(2,3,4,6,12,45)` or is it possible that some rows are not in increasing order, like `(2,4,3,45,12,6)` ?

Comment: @ypercube just checked and yes there all in order 2,3,4,6,12,45 and not 2,4,3,45,12,6. if i could find an example of just 2 consecutive numbers i could figure the rest out.

Answer (score 1):

These will be rather slow queries because you are searching in a quite big table.

Find rows where all 6 numbers are consecutive.

Slow:

```
SELECT *
FROM allposs
WHERE n2 = n1+1
  AND n3 = n2+1
  AND n4 = n3+1
  AND n5 = n4+1
  AND n6 = n5+1
```

---

Faster:

Add a compound index `(n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6)` on your table.
Also add a `(n2,n3,n4,n5,n6)` index, a `(n3,n4,n5,n6)` one, etc..., up to a `(n6)` index.

Then, create a single table with just one column and 49 rows:

```
CREATE TABLE num
  ( i TINYINT
  , PRIMARY KEY (i)
  ) ;
```

Then use this:

```
SELECT 
      ap.*
FROM 
      allposs AS ap
  JOIN
      num
    ON (n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6) = (i,i+1,i+2,i+3,i+4,i+5)
```

---

Find rows where 5 numbers are consecutive.

Slow:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM allposs
    WHERE n2 = n1+1
      AND n3 = n2+1
      AND n4 = n3+1
      AND n5 = n4+1
      AND n6 > n5+1
  UNION
    SELECT *
    FROM allposs
    WHERE n2 > n1+1
      AND n3 = n2+1
      AND n4 = n3+1
      AND n5 = n4+1
      AND n6 = n5+1
```

Faster:

```
SELECT 
      ap.*
FROM 
      allposs AS ap
  JOIN
      num
    ON ( (n1,n2,n3,n4,n5) = (i,i+1,i+2,i+3,i+4) AND n6 > i+5 )
    OR ( n1 < i-1 AND (n2,n3,n4,n5,n6) = (i,i+1,i+2,i+3,i+4) )
```

---

You can use these queries with **[`CREATE TABLE anothertable SELECT ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table-select.html)** or with **[`INSERT INTO anothertable SELECT ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html)** variations to populate more tables if you want to have access to these rows without having to run the queries every time.

Comment: thanks thats great i understand the 6 number example a bit confused on the 5 number one but i am still learning. also how would i put the results into a new table filter1 for for example. would i create table filter1 first then INSERT INTO or could i edit your example and do it all in one.?

Comment: To do it all in one, use the `CREATE TABLE anothertable SELECT ...` syntax (see link for details)

Comment: Thanks i am starting to see the logic in it now i think, you have been really helpful a genius. i am going to create the tables and do a few tests i do have 1 more question which i think will test you but i will save it for a later date when i have had chance to learn a bit more myself and got more used to mysql. Again many thanks.

Comment: You could try playing first with smaller numbers (like a 3/13 lottery), so your queries will not time out or bring the db on its knees, even without indexes. You can also experiment with `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` (and having various indexes) to see how and if indexes will be used.

Comment: could you help again please i have finished creating my database i have the allposs table and 23 filter tables which i want to use to view the remaining results left in allposs when all or some of the ones in my filter tables have been subtracted.? i have looked at where id NOT IN and Left Join examples but can't figure out how to implement either into my query. I am not concerned about the speed just the most basic way of doing it.

Comment: @MarkRobinson: You could use a simple: `SELECT a.* FROM allposs a LEFT JOIN filter f ON f.id = a.id WHERE f.id IS NULL`

Comment: Or `SELECT a.* FROM allposs a WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM filter1 f1 WHERE f1.id=a.id) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM filter2 f2 WHERE f2.id=a.id) ...` for one, two or more filters.

Comment: You could also post a new question (don't forget to include your tables' definitions.)

Comment: Thanks used the second example and got it working. im still learning the basics am getting there though.

Answer (score 0):

Because the numbers in the columns are in order - that is n1 < n2 etc - you can get the lot in *one* query:

```
select *
from (select
  id,n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6,
  (n1=n2-1) + (n2=n3-1)+ (n3=n4-1)+ (n4=n5-1)+ (n5=n6-1) as consecutive_count
  from allposs) x
) where consecutive_count > 0
order by consecutive_count desc, n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6;
```

This query will return all combinations with 6 consecutive numbers first, then all combinations with 5 consecutive numbers, etc and won't return any combinations that have no consecutive numbers.

Having got that you should be able to write your php to process the rows.

If you wanted to use separate queries, change the condition to `where consecutive_count = 3` (for example).

Comment: Thanks for the advice of an alternative way but i need to create the tables for some other tasks. I have finished creating my tables and have 23 filter tables and my main table "allposs" I want to be able to subtract as many of the filter tables as i want away from my main table "allposs" Any ideas as how to do it ? i cant use MINUS operator so would it be left join or something like that ????

Comment: @MarkRobinson I don't know what you are trying to achieve (from a business goal - in life, the technical goal is irrelevant; it's what your solution can *do*, not *how* it does it that matters), but my advice would be to *not* use queries and derived tables: Use application logic if you can. Sometimes databases are awesome at solving problems, and sometimes they're really crap. This seems like it is in the crap bucket. In any case, you need to state your question in terms of a precise outcome giving specified input, which you haven't done.

Comment: I want to be able to view the remaining results in table allposs  once i have taken the ones in my filter tables away.?

Comment: Eg. select * FROM allposs MINUS fiter1, filter3, filter20

Comment: would it be SELECT * FROM allposs WHERE * NOT IN (SELECT * FROM filter1 ) UNION SELECT * FROM allposs WHERE * NOT IN (SELECT * FROM filter3 ) UNION SELECT * FROM allposs WHERE * NOT IN (SELECT * FROM filter20 ) ; or is there another way ?

Comment: NO thats not it ! can't figure it out yet.? thought it would be easy to subtract a few tables and then view the results how wrong i was.